# Word for something which is part of a problem, blamed/feared/thought to be its cause, but isn't?

Tags: terminology, translation, metaphors

**Question.**

What English word do you recommend for

- something which is thought or even openly blamed to be the reason for a real problem, but is at most a part or result of said problem, not its cause

?

Of course,

- scapegoat
- red herring
- EDIT: and also strawman

come to mind, but are, respectively, too harsh, too unspecific, and too much blaming-the-blamer-for-having-set-up-the-perceived-reason.

Do you recommend references in Linguistics or Psychology journals on this topic?

Comment: Sounds like a sacrificial lamb thrown under the bus.  That's my thought, mix your own metaphors.

Comment: **[Victim blaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victim_blaming)**

Comment: just FYI a strawman is not even close to that.  A strawman is an initial proposal with admitted faults that is used as a basis to tease out a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Superficial cause**

> This, gentlemen, is my profound conviction: I believe that we are at this moment sleeping on a volcano. I am profoundly convinced of it 
>   I was saying just now that this evil would sooner or later, I know not how or whence it will come, bring with it a most serious revolution: be assured that that is so.
>   When I come to investigate what, at different times, in different periods, among different peoples, has been the effective cause that has brought about the downfall of the governing classes, I perceive this or that event, man, or accidental or **superficial cause**; but, believe me, the real reason, the effective reason that causes men to lose political power is that they have become unworthy to retain it.

http://www.speeches-usa.com/Transcripts/alexis_deTocqueville-gale.html

emphasis mine.

Answer (score 1):

**Putative cause** [MW definition of putative](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/putative)

The cause assumed or supposed to be the reason for something

Answer (score 1):

How about, a ***symptom***, not the disease?

Answer (score 0):

I think your strategy of looking to logical fallacies is a good one.

Other recommendations I have are:

**straw man**

> "a common form of argument and is an informal fallacy based on giving the impression of refuting an opponent's argument, while refuting an argument that was not advanced by that opponent"

**metonymy**

> "a figure of speech in which a thing or concept is referred to by the name of something closely associated with that thing or concept"

Comment: Thanks. "strawman", which I should have included in the list of terms-with-the-wrong-nuance, for the purposes of this question has the unintended connotation of "having been intentionally set up by someone", whereas here the metaphor/word is supposed to also convey that the blamer/fearer is being misled by the thing in question, while not having set it up themselves.